# Gradle configuration.apt definition

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-annotations

I'm starting to use Gradle on Android Studio and when I was adding AndroidAnnotations support on my project, I found on google that I had to add the following on my gradle.build file:

```
configurations {
    apt
}
```

-

```
dependencies {
    apt 'com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations:2.7.1'
    compile 'com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:2.7.1'
}
```

-

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    aptOutput = file("${project.projectDir}/gen")
    println "****************************"
    println "variant: ${variant.name}"
    println "manifest:  ${variant.processResources.manifestFile}"
    println "aptOutput:  ${aptOutput}"
    println "****************************"

    variant.javaCompile.doFirst {
        println "*** compile doFirst ${variant.name}"
        aptOutput.mkdirs()
        variant.javaCompile.options.compilerArgs += [
                '-processorpath', configurations.apt.getAsPath(),
                '-AandroidManifestFile=' + variant.processResources.manifestFile,
                '-s', aptOutput
        ]
    }
}
```

The first thing I can't find anywhere in the web is what the apt means. I've looked through the gradle docs (I looked for the word apt) and didn't find anything.

Another doubt is, since I've already added the annotation library on the Preferences menu, why do I need to write the last script to write the generated files?

Thank you very much.

Comment: APT stands for Annotation Processing Tool ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/ )

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I have something to look for :)